# SQLiteLog: (1) near "manId" Syntax error while joining in tables together in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am  joining three tables `MANUFACTURERS_TABLE`, `TBL_JOB_ADDRESS`, `TBL_APPLIANCES` whereas creating two foreign keys in `TBL_APPLIANCES` getting an error as stated in the title of the question. Having looked at the previous questions & answer, I'm not making the mistakes outlined in those questions.

Manufacturers Table

```
//columsn for manufacturer table
public static final String KEY_MANROWID = "manId";   // error-some
public static final String KEY_MANFACTURERNAME = "manufacturer_name";
```

JobAddress table

```
//columsn for job address table
public static final String KEY_JOB_ADDRESSROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESSOFPLACE = "address_of_place";
```

Appliances Table

```
public static final String KEY_APPLIANCES_ROWID = "appliances_id";
public static final String KEY_APPLIANCES_MANIFACTURERS_ID = "appliance_manufacturers_id";

public static final String KEY_APPLIANCES_MODEL = "appliances_model";
public static final String KEY_APPLIANCES_TYPE = "appliances_type";
public static final String KEY_APPLIANCES_SERIAL = "appliances_serial";
public static final String KEY_APPLIANCES_SERVICE_INTERVAL=  
    "appliances_service_interval";
public static final String KEY_APPLIANCES_JOB_ADDRESS_ID =    
    "appliances_jobaddress_id";
public static final String KEY_APPLIANCES_ENGINEERS_ID = "appliances_engineers_id";
public static final String KEY_APPLIANCES_DATE = "appliances_date";
```

Creating appliances table with both forieng keys

```
// appliance table referencing manufacturers & job adress table
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TBL_APPLIANCES + " (" 
                    + KEY_APPLIANCES_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + KEY_APPLIANCES_MODEL + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_APPLIANCES_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_APPLIANCES_SERIAL + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_APPLIANCES_SERVICE_INTERVAL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
                    + KEY_APPLIANCES_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_JOB_ADDRESSROWID + " INTEGER, "
                    + " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_APPLIANCES_JOB_ADDRESS_ID+") REFERENCES "+TBL_JOB_ADDRESS+" ("+KEY_JOB_ADDRESSROWID+") "
                    + KEY_MANROWID + " INTEGER, "
                    + " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_APPLIANCES_MANIFACTURERS_ID+") REFERENCES "+MANUFACTURERS_TABLE+" ( "+KEY_MANROWID+" ));"
                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table constraints such as `FOREIGN KEY` must come after column specifications.

Move the

```
+ KEY_MANROWID + " INTEGER, "
```

above the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

Comment: Thanks pal, didn't know that but now I know :)